# Updating table from js file Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm trying to update a table with data that is read from a textile. The textfile is correctly read and inserted into the constructor. The Table however in the HTML does not update. Why is this and how can I fix it? Not the html file that contains the table is not the root view that is rendered when I run the Electron app.

There is a home page and from the home page I navigate to this recipe page. I'm not sure if this is the cause. But that's why I added a timeout function to give me time to navigate to the correct view before running the func.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

// Mark ALL Constructors
class Recipe {
  constructor() {
    this.instructions = [];
    this.image = 'path';
    this.ingredients = [];
    this.description = '';
    this.nutrition_facts = [];
    this.cuisine = '';
    this.favorite = false;
    this.restrictions = [];
    this.difficulty = 0;
    this.review = '';
  }
}

var recipeArray = []; // store all recipes

function read_file(filePath) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    const lines = data.split('\n');
    const recipe = new Recipe();
    // I trim all of them to get rid of whitespaces around
    recipe.description = lines[0].trim();
    recipe.ingredients = lines[1].split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    recipe.image = lines[2].trim();
    recipe.nutrition_facts = lines[3].trim().split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    recipe.cuisine = lines[4].trim();
    recipe.favorite = lines[5].trim() === 'true'; // check to make sure type right and equal to true if not its auto gonna be false
    recipe.restrictions = lines[6].split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    recipe.difficulty = parseInt(lines[7].trim(), 10);
    recipe.review = lines[8].trim(); // should this be int like 8/10 or string?

    // instructions can be any length starting from the 9th line
    for (let i = 9; i < lines.length; i++) {
      recipe.instructions.push(lines[i].trim());
    }
    recipeArray.push(recipe);

    // Send the parsed recipe to the renderer process
    mainWindow.webContents.send('recipeData', recipe);
  });
}

function populateRecipies(fileName) {
  const filePath = __dirname + '/' + fileName;
  read_file(filePath);
}

let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

  mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    // Access the document object after the DOM is ready
    setTimeout(() => {
      populateRecipies('testRecipe.txt');
    }, 10000);
  });
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
});

// Quit the app when all windows are closed (except on macOS)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// Create a new window when the app is activated (on macOS)
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ALL Recipes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        ALL Recipes
    </header>
    <main>
      <div>
        <table id="table">           
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>NAME:</th>
              <th>Ingrediants:</th>
              <th>ImageURL:</th>
              <th>facts:</th>
              <th>Cuisine:</th>
              <th>Is favorite:</th>
              <th>restrictions</th>
              <th>difficulty</th>
              <th>review</th>
              <th>instructions:</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      &copy; SOFTWARE 1 GROUP
    </footer>
    <script>
        const tableBody = document.querySelector('#table tbody');
      
        // Listen for the recipe data from the main process
        ipcRenderer.on('recipeData', (event, recipe) => {
          // Update the table with the recipe data
          console.log('Recipe data received:', recipe);
          updateTable(recipe);
        });
      
        // Function to update the HTML table with recipe data
        function updateTable(recipe) {
          const row = tableBody.insertRow();
          row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${recipe.description}</td>
            <td>${recipe.ingredients.join(', ')}</td>
            <td>${recipe.image}</td>
            <td>${recipe.nutrition_facts.join(', ')}</td>
            <td>${recipe.cuisine}</td>
            <td>${recipe.favorite}</td>
            <td>${recipe.restrictions.join(', ')}</td>
            <td>${recipe.difficulty}</td>
            <td>${recipe.review}</td>
            <td>${recipe.instructions.join('<br>')}</td>
          `;
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

```
const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false, // THIS FIXES THE ISSUES>
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

  mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("dd");
      populateRecipies('testRecipe.txt');
    }, 10000);
  });

  ipcMain.on('recipePageReady', () => {
    console.log("called");
    populateRecipies('testRecipe.txt');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) is correctly imported in your HTML file. Your HTML snippet does not show the import of `ipcRenderer`. Add this line to your script tag in HTML:

```html
<script>
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
// rest of your script
</script>
```

Make sure the DOM is fully loaded before your script tries to manipulate it. That is usually done by placing script tags at the end of the body or using [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event). Add error handling in the `updateTable` function to catch any issues that might occur when updating the DOM.
Make sure `mainWindow` is the correct reference to the window where your HTML table resides.

---

More generally, consider that the [use of `setTimeout` is unreliable](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7079) for waiting for navigation. It is better to trigger the data sending when the recipe page is ready. Consider using IPC messages to signal when to send the data.

In your main process, you could set up an IPC listener that waits for a signal indicating that the recipe page is ready. Upon receiving this signal, you can *then* call the `populateRecipies` function to send the recipe data to the renderer process.

Update your `createWindow` function in the main process as follows:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
  // existing code to create mainWindow 

  ipcMain.on('recipePageReady', () => {
    populateRecipies('testRecipe.txt');
  });
};
```

In your renderer process (the recipe page HTML/JavaScript), you will need to send a signal to the main process once the page is ready. That can be done by emitting an IPC message to the main process.

```html
<script>
  // existing code 

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('recipePageReady');
  });
</script>
```

You would get the workflow:

```
[ Electron Main Process ]
   |__ [ BrowserWindow ] -- Loads --> [ index.html ]
   |__ [ ipcMain.on('recipePageReady', ...) ] -- Waits for signal from renderer

[ Renderer Process (Recipe Page) ]
   |__ [ DOMContentLoaded ] -- Page is ready, Sends IPC --> [ 'recipePageReady' ]
   |__ [ ipcRenderer.on('recipeData', ...) ] -- Receives --> [ Recipe Data ]
   |__ [ updateTable() ] -- Updates --> [ HTML Table ]
```

---

As noted by [the OP ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18070009/ahmed) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491756/updating-table-from-js-file-electron/77498681#comment136627716_77498681), a critical for integrating the Electron main process and renderer process, especially when using certain Electron APIs like `ipcRenderer` is the setting `contextIsolation: false` in the `webPreferences` of the `BrowserWindow` object.

The **[context isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)** is a security feature in Electron that isolates the main world (your JavaScript) from the renderer world (internal Electron code).
When `contextIsolation` is `true`, it prevents the renderer from accessing Electron's internal APIs directly. That is recommended for security reasons, but can make some integrations more complex.

`contextIsolation: false` disables context isolation, which allows your renderer script to access Electron APIs (like `ipcRenderer`) directly. That can simplify code, but it is less secure because it exposes the Electron APIs and potentially Node.js APIs to the renderer process.

The updated `createWindow` function, as provided by the OP, looks like:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false, // Disable context isolation
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

  mainWindow.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("dd");
      populateRecipies('testRecipe.txt');
    }, 10000);
  });

  ipcMain.on('recipePageReady', () => {
    console.log("called");
    populateRecipies('testRecipe.txt');
  });
};
```

While setting `contextIsolation: false` solves the immediate problem of integrating IPC communication between the main and renderer processes, it is important to be aware of the security implications. In a production application, especially one that loads remote content, it is recommended to keep `contextIsolation` enabled and use secure methods to expose only what is necessary from the main process to the renderer process.

Also, you might want to evaluate whether `nodeIntegration` should be enabled, as this exposes Node.js APIs to the renderer process, which could be a security risk if not handled carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer fixes the majority of the problem. The final step was to set contextIsolation: false. Ive added the example in the update of my question, Maybe add this to your solution

Comment: @ahmed OK, good catch. I have edited the answer to include your example, but also to comment on it.